# Ruby variable each loop substitution

Tags: ruby, variables, substitution

I need to replace X_VARIABLE in 2 places.
For the first X_VARIABLE I want to keep the text 'remove'
For the second X_VARIABLE I want to keep 'd_cars_path'

```
<% @cars.each do |x| %>
    <% @a = @b.send(x) %>
    <% if @a == true %>
      <%= button_to "removeX_VARIABLE", X_VARIABLEd_cars_path(:id => @user.id), class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am looking for some help with the variable substitution syntax. Thanks.

Comment: do you want the result like **<%= button_to "remove", d_cars_path(:id => @user.id), class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write:

```
<% @cars.each do |x| %>
  <% if @b.send(x) %>
    <%= button_to "remove#{x}", 
          send(:"#{x}d_cars_path", id: @user.id), 
          class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 I prefer this approach (and I gave a haml version of it too).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the send(: ) function.

Comment: @Tony you used `send` in your code :-) maybe you didn't know that you can use it with implicit object (`self`).